# Convergence of Moment Generating Function Given a Bound on the Random Variable, ie $\Bbb{E}(e^{\lambda X} | X \le K) \uparrow \Bbb{E}(e^{\lambda X})$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

I'm trying to show that, given an integrable random variable in $\Bbb R$, for all $\lambda \ge 0$,
$$\Bbb{E}(e^{\lambda X} | X \le K) \uparrow \Bbb{E}(e^{\lambda X}).$$
I can show that the left hand side is bounded above by the right hand side, but I can neither show that it is increasing nor that the limit is actually the right hand side.

This is what I have so far. I just did the standard thing, writing $Y = e^{\lambda X}$:
\begin{align}
E(Y)
&= E(Y|X \le K)P(X \le K) + E(Y|X > K)P(X > K) \\
&= E(Y|X \le K) + (E(Y|X > K) - E(Y|X \le K))P(X>K) \\
&\ge E(Y|X \le K),
\end{align}
since $E(Y|X \le K) \le e^{\lambda K} \le E(Y|X > K)$. Further, since $X$ is integrable, we know that $P(X > K) \to 0$ and $K \to \infty$.

This is as far as I can get. I am having issues since $E(Y|K>K)$ is unbounded as $K \to \infty$ (if $\lambda > 0$; in fact, as above, $E(Y|X>K) \ge e^{\lambda K} \to \infty$ as $K \to \infty$. I can't even see why necessarily $(E(Y|X > K) - E(Y|X \le K))P(X>K)$ is decreasing as a function of $K$.

Any advice would be most appreciated. However, if you've seen my questions before, you may know that I have a general disclaimer: **please do not post full solutions!** I'm trying to learn maths, and just having someone tell me the answer doesn't really help. If I just wanted the answer, I'd wait until my supervision this week. What I would like is a **very minor push in the right direction**; I can then (hopefully!) do the rest myself, and learn from it. Thank you.

PS: Sorry about the awful title -- if anyone can think of a better one, then please just change it and (providing it is better!) I'll accept the change.

Comment: Take the very first equality for $E(Y)$ (assuming it exists) and send $K\infty$. The second summand $\to 0$ and the first summand is $\sim E(Y|X\le K)$.

Comment: Yeah, I mean, that's obviously true (providing the question is right!), but I don't know how to prove that the second one goes to $0$. One term is growing and the other decaying. By the equality, the term is certainly bounded, but without assuming the answer I can't see how to prove that the second term goes to $0$! :)

Comment: I mean, for all you know, we might have that $E(Y|X \ge K) \to E(Y)*(9/10)$ and $E(Y|X>K)P(X>K) \to E(Y)*(1/10)$, if you see what I mean? :)

Comment: Just rewrite the second summand as $E(Y;X>K)$. Then it becomes obvious.

Comment: By that I assume you mean $E(Y, 1(X>K))$ (indicator function)? For some reason I had this idea that because it was expectation, not probability, I couldn't combine the two like that. Kill me now!

Comment: I mean $E(Y1(X>K))$.

Comment: Urgh, yeah, sorry. Otherwise I'd be adding a scalar to a vector. I've spent ages on this too, and it's just a simple application of Bayes! The rest of the sheet was pretty hard, and I've managed all but three parts of questions -- why couldn't I get this, haha!?